# How do I update a column to be a list of values from another table using Postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

sorry I'm quite new to SQL so I'm having trouble finding out how to write the queries. Let me explain what's happening:

In **Postgres**, I have table_a with a column of "account_name", and a column to be calculated based on another table, table_b; we'll call this calculated column "column_a" to match the title of this question. table_b has a column that should match the values of the "account_name" column, or not. table_b also has a column with "name".

**I want to populate table_a's "column_a" with a list of "name"'s from table_b where "account_name" of table_b equals the "account_name" value from table_a whenever table_b is updated or a new row is inserted.**

**table_a:**

| column_a | account_name |
| --- | --- |
| null | Worker |
| null | Boss |

**table_b:**

| name | account_name |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Worker |
| Alice | Boss |
| Tom | Worker |
| Brad | Investor |

*Once populated, table_a should look like this:*

| column_a | account_name |
| --- | --- |
| Bob,Tom | Worker |
| Alice | Boss |

I know I have to create a trigger to run a function whenever table_b is updated or had a row inserted, and I also have to define this function.

However, I'm quite new to SQL and looking at similar questions to this is really hard for me to find what's applicable or convertible to my situation. So once I figure this out, other things should come a bit easier for me. Would really appreciate someone helping me out and explaining *why* for as much as you can.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I have the feeling this is an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do this? Comma separated lists are an anti-pattern

Comment: It may be actually; was just intended to be able to get a nice list into Python without adding more lines to the code. Maybe I'm looking at how to use the database wrong/atypically. I can do it in python, just thought it'd be a good way to learn postgres/sql while also getting done what I need to get done.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation function string_agg is  a subselet, will return only 1 value, whih you can use to update

> ```
> UPDATE tablea ta
> SET "column_a" = (SELECT string_agg("name",',') FROM tableb WHERE "account_name" = ta."account_name")
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tablea
> ```
>
> ```
> column_a | account_name
> :------- | :-----------
> Bob,Tom  | Worker      
> Alice    | Boss
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7dcddcccf62427485aeffe253b146422)*